# Frontal Elevations VS Military Press: Differences in terms of muscles used, hypertrophy and speed of progression in terms of number of repetitions?

Tags: shoulders, dumbbells

I would want to know what are these differences between dumbells frontal elevations and dumbells military press?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Front raises are an isolation exercise designed to target the anterior deltoid.

Shoulder pressing is a compound exercise which also involves the triceps and lateral deltoids.